# How to add attachment using Java in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've worked though most of the examples on Stack, but I'm still having an issue being able to add an attachment to the MS Graph API using Java. Some of the examples posted use methods that are no longer being used.

Here's the code inside the create message method:

```
    FileAttachment fileAttachment = new FileAttachment();
    fileAttachment.name = "Example text file";
    Path path = Paths.get("/Users/user/Desktop/Text.txt");
    fileAttachment.contentBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

.
.
.

```
  graphClient.me()
                .sendMail(UserSendMailParameterSet
                        .newBuilder()
                        .withMessage(message)
                        .withSaveToSentItems(saveToSentItems)
                        .build())
                .buildRequest()
                .post();
```

But, I can't find a method to add this attachment to the message.

I'm brand new at the MS Graph API, but have spent some hours on this already so I'm thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Attachment can be added to a `message.attachments`

Example:

```
FileAttachment fileAttachment = new FileAttachment();
fileAttachment.name = "Example text file";
Path path = Paths.get("/Users/user/Desktop/Text.txt");
fileAttachment.contentBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);

LinkedList<Attachment> attachmentsList = new LinkedList<Attachment>();
attachmentsList.add(fileAttachment);
AttachmentCollectionResponse attachmentCollectionResponse = new AttachmentCollectionResponse();
attachmentCollectionResponse.value = attachmentsList;
AttachmentCollectionPage attachmentCollectionPage = new AttachmentCollectionPage(attachmentCollectionResponse, null);
// add to your message
message.attachments = attachmentCollectionPage;
```

Resources:

[Create a message with a file attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#example-3--create-a-message-with-a-file-attachment-and-send-the-message)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this approach already. This gives an error: "Error message: The property 'contentBytes' does not exist on type 'microsoft.graph.attachment'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type."  The code all compiles fine, however.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working!!! ...Check this URL below for the solution:

[MS Documentation Error Solution: ] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/527635/graph-api-attachment-add-not-working.html

Per the link above, the MS example code referenced was missing the line of code that makes sending the attachment work, at least for me.

```
fileAttachment.oDataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment";
```

Thanks to all!